# How to increase a number for the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I would like to display an increased number (starting with 1 and ending with 47) for each class called `quiz_image`.

The HTML looks kind of like this:

```
<div class="quiz_image">
    Content here
</div>

<div class="quiz_image">
    Content here
</div>

<div class="quiz_image">
    Content here
</div>
```

In order to display the number before the class `quiz_image`, I have tried it like this:

```
var i = 1;
$('.quiz_image').before(i);
i++;
```

In my code above the number will not increase, since there is probably a loop needed and I have no idea how to start a loop in this case. I hope somebody can help out on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use jQuery to get a selector it will return an array of elements. So you'll want to loop through them. I would suggest with something like the jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function, which natively provides you with a 0 based index, you could try something like:

```
$('.quiz_image').each(function(i){
    $(this).before(i + 1); // add one so we dont start at 0
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's just what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Loopin all   `quiz_image` and use  their index numbers

```
$('.quiz_image').each(function(index){

         $(this).before(index+1);

    });
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/m57eb0pp/)

Answer (score 0):

before function in jQuery sets the content  before the specified element , and it also accepts the  function so we can do it like the below example.

> **index** function Search for a given element from among the matched elements

```
$('.quiz_image').before(function(){
return $('.quiz_image').index(this)+1
});
```

Comment: if you dont 'pre-fetch' `$('.quiz_image')` and save it as a variable, this code will perform a DOM traversal for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change the class for each image? 
Rather give each one an ID.

```
<div class="quiz_image"></div>
<script>
counter = 0;
var quiz_id = $(".quiz_image").prop("id");
$(".quiz_image").each(function(){
counter++;
quiz_id = quiz_id + counter
$(".quiz_image").prop("id",quiz_id);
});
```

Comment: `.each()` has an in-built 'counter'